# jQuery UI Autocomplete, load results to a different location(div)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am converting from YUI to jQuery and can't see a way to load the results of the autocomplete into a div or other such container.

I want to be able to populate a div with formatted results, including an image based on the return, not just a simple drop down from the input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://so.lucafilosofi.com/jquery-ui-autocomplete-load-results-to-a-different-locationdiv/

> updated

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    open: function(event, ui) {
        $($('ul.ui-autocomplete').removeAttr('style').hide()).appendTo('div').show();
    }
});
```

then access single element by it's class `.ui-menu-item`

example would be

```
$('.ui-autocomplete li').each(function() {
if ( $(this).text() == 'javascript' )
     $(this).append('<img src="" alt="" />');
});
```

Comment: And you can then add something like #your-append-container .ui-autocomplete {
  position: static !important;
} and that way it won't be in the air anymore and it will stick inside that container

Comment: @gibberish tnx for the check... i have updated both link and code.